# Custom action in CakePHP ACL aros_acos

Tags: cakephp-1.3, acl

I'm following this ACL tutorial [here](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/how-to-use-cakephps-access-control-lists/) and I noticed that the aros_acos table contains C-R-U-D column.

If I have a custom admin-only action (which I call admin_dashboard) and would only want the Admin group to view it, how do I go about populating the aros_acos table?

I have tried creating a column in the aros_acos table called "admin_dashboard" and added this code `$this->Acl->allow('Admin', 'Event', array('admin_dashboard'));` but it doesn't seem to populate the admin_dashboard in the Admin row with the value of 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The aros_acos **table** has to be populated either "by hand" (i.e. using sl statement) or using the cake-shell. The tutorial you are referring to seems to be well written, and I have not found it is pretending that function changes the table: try to read it again.

The statement `$this->Acl->allow()` is intended to just programatically allow an action which would be otherwise denied by the aros_acos table (or by a previous `deny()`).

You may better want to set up routing to map and use `admin_` actions (maybe reading in the [bakery](http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/nate/2009/07/14/secrets-of-admin-routing)).

Comment: Regardless of what the tutorial says... if you look at the code for `$this->Acl->allow()` you will see that it is indeed designed to change the aros_acos table.